# Angular ngResource handle 404 api error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, angularjs, api, angular-resource

i have a Rails API

> Ex. example.com/v1/portfolio/{{ id }}

and i'm using AngularJS ngResource to handle the data with get.

```
myAppServices.factory('Portfolio', ['$resource', function($resource){
    return $resource('api/v1/portfolios/:id/', { id:'@id'}, {
        query: {
            method:'GET', 
            params:{id:'@id'},
            isArray:true
        }
    });
}]);
```

How can i handle the Not found 404 Error if the API does not have an Entry

> Ex. example.com/v1/portfolio/blabla

i mean how can i make it 404 like when u enter http://www.google.com/sdfa check the network status code you'll find it 404.

For more information am using Prerender.io service to Render the website for Search Engines.

Comment: can you post your  get method ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the prerender-status-code meta tag to return a 404 to the crawler. The documentation is here: https://prerender.io/documentation/best-practices

Basically, just add  to the  of the page if the page should return a 404 to crawlers. Prerender.io will detect that status code and return that to the crawler instead of a 200.

Feel free to send an email to support@prerender.io if you have any other questions about that. We're happy to help!

Answer (score 2):

You can use $promise like this:

```
var resource = $resource('api/v1/portfolios/:id/');

resource.get({id: 123}).$promise.then(function(todo) {
   // success
}, function(errResponse) {
   // handle 404 here
});
```

Comment: i mean how can i make it 404 like when u enter http://www.google.com/sdfa check the network status code you'll find it 404.

Comment: I would do that on the server side, i.e. try to get with the given :id and catch if it does not exist and return a response with status 404

Comment: am already doing that but it's giving the 404 for the api route only like (404 example.com/api/v1/portfolio/blabla) but it's not sending the status code to the main website (example.com) it sends 200 OK

Comment: I don't know Ruby but if you post your server side code, I would try to understand and help